# How to use Timestampable in a Trait with Platform API groups

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, stofdoctrineextensions

Now i have a lot of entities with:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
#[Groups(['article_category:output'])]
/**
 * @Timestampable(on="create")
 */
private \DateTime $createdAt;

public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTime
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}
```

And i want to put it inside Trait.
But each entity has its own normalization group (like 'article_category:output').
How can I make this field always available from the API Platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we did:

use a group in your trait, e.g. `timestampable`

```
trait TimestampableEntity
{
    /**
     * ...
     * @Groups({"timestampable"})
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    ...
}
```

Then whenever you want to expose the timestamps, add them to your config (you can add multiple groups to an operation)

```
<?php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations= {
 *          "get" = {
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"appointment:read", "timestampable"}},
 *           },
 *     },
 * )
 */
class Appointment
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for this simple yet effective solution.

Comment: It's works but this TimestampableEntity is a vendor so  composant  update erase your code !!

Comment: @JérémyCornut Of course you need that trait in your repo. You can use the one from the extension as a start and make the necessary changes. In the end it's just two fields with getters/setters.