# Entity with TimestampableEntity trait fails on PUT operation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com, doctrine-extensions

I'm on a fresh install of API Platform (v3.2.7) and I'm using `Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity`

This is my entity (Greeting example)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Greeting
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public string $name = "";

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and my config/services.yaml

```
gedmo.listener.timestampable:
    class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: 'prePersist' }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: 'onFlush' }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: 'loadClassMetadata' }
```

It woks fine on `POST` operation, but it fails when doing a `PUT`. I get this error

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]:
> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be
> null

The versions I'm using are: symfony 6.4.1, doctrine 2.12, gedmo 3.14

Comment: created_at is supposed to be updated on prePersist, so it would make sense in a POST operation. However it should not be the case for an update PUT. I guess you are not sending the created_at in your request ? so it's trying to update with a null value ?

Comment: That's right. I'm not sending created_at (and I shouldn't). in both `POST` and `PUT` the only data I'm sending is `{"name":"something"}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69915735/11350193 should be what you are looking for

Comment: that is if I want expose created_at in my response while defining groups. That is not what's happening to me. It just fails in a simple PUT operation

Comment: Did you try doing a put operation with a created_at date inside your request ? It would probably work because created_at is overwritten as null by your put request. That's why groups would help

Comment: it worked,but again, I should be passing that propery, in fact the value of created at is now overwritten. using groups didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`. So I can edit a partial entity and the trait still updates the `updated_at` field